# Concatenate Day number + Day Name JavaScript JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this for loop, so I need to join the name of the Day in the array with his respective number day.

```js
var weekday = ["sunday","monday", "tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"];
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var today = new Date();
var actual = today.getDate();
var endTime = today.getDate() + 7;
var startTime = today.getDate() - 7;

$("h1").html("Today:"+weekday[today.getDay()] +
   today.getDate()+months[today.getMonth()]).addClass('current-day');

for(i = startTime + 1; i < actual; i++){
  $('.start-date').append('<div>Day # '+ i +'</div>' + 'Name  of Day'+weekday[i.getDay()]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="start-date">
</section>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<section class="end-date"></section>
```

Thanks

Comment: What have **you** tried? Also it would be easier if you just paste that code here.

Comment: Also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: What are you expecting to see next to "Day #9" and next to "Name of Day" (just after "Day #9")?

Comment: Yes, i hope Day #9 - Saturday Day #10 Sunday

Comment: I really don't understand this. In what way would Day#9 be Saturday if Today is Friday? Do you mean the day of the month?

Comment: I was edited the question , with error for reference. :)